# Forest environment inside forest node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, forest

Is it possible to have a forest environment inside a forest node? It does not work when I write the following:

```
\begin{forest}
    [$a$
     [$b$]
     [$\texttt{apply}\left(
        \begin{forest}
            [b
             [c]
             [d]
            ]
        \end{forest}
     \right)$]
    ]
\end{forest}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This won't work.

However, you can save the inner tree into a box and then put the box contents into the node of the outer tree, as shown below.  (I also changed the baseline of the inner tree to its center, so that the inner tree fits nicely within the brackets.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newbox\mybox

\begin{document}

\setbox\mybox=\hbox{%
  \begin{forest}
    begin draw/.append code={[baseline=(current bounding box)]}
    [b
      [c]
      [d]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
}

\begin{forest}
  [$a$
    [$b$]
    [$\texttt{apply}\left(\box\mybox\right)$]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: the result of the compilation]